# Git push process is running but project not pushing

Tags: bash, git, push, project

when i push to my git repository, the git bash is running but its not pushing my codes into the repo and no error messages. i tried many times with different projects and finally i pushed my simple calculator project that i develop. but still not working. when i close the git bash its say's it still running on the session. i don't know what to do right now.

Git Bash

[image]

When I close the Git bash

[image]

I re-install the git bash and also create a new git account to push my project. but same result.

Comment: What is the command that you are using to push ?

Comment: Try to run `git push --verbose origin master`. Also try `git push` for a different repository or different origin server. Maybe the problem is with the server not responding.

Comment: Sounds like a network issue to me, probably a firewall or simply a wrong repository URL.

Comment: There appears to be a disconnect between Git bash and your mingw64 utility.  Maybe you omitted a switch which would have it abandon when the command that is encapsulated is terminated, leading to mingw process persistence ... OR ... (we're talking Windows here) there might be some open files in background which were not closed when GitBash closed.

Comment: @error404 I used "git push origin master" to push the files

Comment: @user14967413 yes I used that command. same result :(

Comment: Try with mobaxterm https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/download-home-edition.html Installer edition